# Finding e-mail addresses using XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I have been trying to extract e-mail addresses from the following code for quite a while now, using xpath, with no success...

http://pastie.org/4172907 (line 78)

This is what I tried so far:

```
//tr/td/div[@class='geTextA5'][2]/a
```

I have been messing around with xpath for over three hours, tried many different variations. I am very new to xpath, so I am hoping theres an easier way to accomplish this.

I appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am new to xpath. I was able to extract other types of information using xpath on the website without any trouble... The website isn't mine btw so I cannot really make any changes to the code, only work with what I got:/

Comment: Line 78 seems to be `<div style="margin: 5px; "/>`. I would recommend reading up on basic XPath predicates and functions. W3Schools has some content on this; also there's ZVON.org.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are assured that all the e-mail have a mailto hyperlink like in the example, then you can try the following xpath.

```
//a[starts-with(@href, 'mailto')]/text()
```

Comment: When I tried the above command, I get an 'invalid syntax' error in the scrapy shell. Full command is: response.xpath('//a[starts-with(@href,'mailto')]/text()') and the error message points to 'mailto'

Answer (score 3):

To add further, if you want to parse emails from text but they aren't wrapped in an anchor:

```
//*[contains(text(), '@')]
```

Comment: If I am using this on a webpage it is also giving result from the source code. Is there a way it only reads the frontend text and not the source