# Getting the one and only e-mail address on a page using XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I have been trying to extract an e-mail address from a website using XPath. There is only 1 email address on the entire page. Is there an easy way to reference that one e-mail address using XPath?

something like: `//a/contains(@href,'@')`

I tried something similar to what I have posted above with no success, I'd appreciate any advice on a reliable way to pull e-mail address using Xpath. Assume there is only 1 e-mail address on the page with no identifying information other than a simple `<a href="mailto:example@george.com">` tag.

Thank you

Comment: "from a website" is not much data to go on. Are you sure the website is valid XML at all, otherwise there's not much XPath-ing to do...

Comment: @Jan Doggen, I did not include the specific website on purpose because making XPath work for one particular site only, is of no use to me, I was trying to look for a uniform solution, assuming the XML is valid, get the first e-mail address found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//a[contains(text(), "@")]
```

That will return you the node containing the e-mail address (well, an `@` sign at least), not the e-mail address itself.

If you can be sure the node contains *only* the e-mail address and no other adjacent text, you can get it with

```
//a[contains(text(), "@")]/text()
```

If you *can't* be sure, you'd have to string-handle it out of the text manually. This is going to be pretty painful in XPath 1.0 since, depending on your implementation, you probably don't have access to any REGEX functionality.

Comment: I don't understand your question. And the link you gave says I need to login and its source code doesn't contain any e-mail addresses.

Comment: Yeap, the XPath I gave you will do it. See this [XML Playground](http://www.xmlplayground.com/u6226D) for proof.

Comment: I don't know about the Google Docs API but from a purely XPath point of view, the path I gave meets your requirements, as shown in the playground session. Are you sure the source code of the page is well-formed XML, i.e. that it's traversable at all? You might need to re-tag the question to incorporate Google Docs so people in that sphere can help.

Comment: No probs - sorry we couldn't crack the case

Comment: I believe //a[starts-with(@href, 'mailto')]/text() should solve the purpose.
I have also mentioned this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11267266/finding-e-mail-addresses-using-xpath